# Creating a new product in magento

Tags: php, magento

I just started Magento development and starting to get a hang of it. I found some examples on how to create a new product and this code:

```
$p2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$p2->setSku('art002');
$p2->setAttributeSetId(2);
$p2->setPrice(20);
$p2->save();
```

is supposed to do that. However, when running this code, it takes forever (CPU usage peaks to 100%) and it never actually finishes.

I had the same issue with updating a product, but got that working like this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
    ->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('price'=>10), 1);
```

but I fail to see how I could use that to create a new product.

(Background: I am trying to create a interface module to a WMS, so I need to be able to upload/update products, as well as update stock.)

Answer (score 0):

I repeated your code on my test machine, but couldn't reproduce your problem. I think you need to change your index mode from 'update on save' to 'update when scheduled', which is in Admin >> System >> Advanced >> Index Management

Comment: OK, I tried this, and it didn't work. But, I didn't find the problem. My hook is on product update. So, I update a product in a product update hook, creating an endless loop. My fault.